# Two Way binding not working when set via Code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, winrt-xaml

I am creating dynamic control in code behind and setting it's visibility property binding to the property in the code behind. But when the property value is changed, it's not updating visibility of the control.

Binding:

```
        Binding assetsVisibilityBinding = new Binding();
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Source = this;
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("IsLocalSearchEnabled");
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Converter = Resources["BooleanToVisibilityConverter"] as IValueConverter;
        assetsStackPanel.SetBinding(StackPanel.VisibilityProperty, assetsVisibilityBinding);
```

Property(Using fody):

```
  public bool IsLocalSearchEnabled { get; set; }
```

Comment: First thing I'd do is open the compiled binary up in justDecompile and make sure fody is actually rewriting your assembly.  Also, use a tool like Snoop (not sure if it works with uwps) to examine your bindings at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your class which contains the property needs to implement the interface

```
INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Let's assume your class name be **A**

then snippet will be

```
class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public bool isLocalSearchEnabled = false;
    public bool IsLocalSearchEnabled
    {
         get { return isLocalSearchEnabled ;}
         set { isLocalSearchEnabled  = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("IsLocalSearchEnabled");
    }
}
```

What happens here when you implement INotifyPropertyChanged is the event **PropertyChanged**
is triggered when the value of isLocalSearchEnabled is set (regardless of old value and new value) and OnPropertyChanged is called with the name of Public property

Comment: Thanks. But as mentioned in the post I am actually using Fody(github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged). Which automatically implements that

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface, please see the detailed example  [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. But as mentioned in the post I am actually using Fody(https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged). Which automatically implements that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the assetsStackPanel DataContext the binding need the source ,that you should set the DataContext ont only set the source.

If you set the property in this in xaml.cs that you should make it public.

```
Binding assetsVisibilityBinding = new Binding();
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Source = this;
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("IsLocalSearchEnabled");
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Converter = Resources["BooleanToVisibilityConverter"] as IValueConverter;
        assetsStackPanel.DataContex=this;
        assetsStackPanel.SetBinding(StackPanel.VisibilityProperty, assetsVisibilityBinding);
```

For I have not read frameWork ,I think you can try use property by INotifyPropertyChanged to know whether code is right.

And you can use `BindingOperations.SetBinding`

Try use resharper in xaml and write `Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=IsLocalSearchEnabled}",mode=TwoWay`.If it can work that is mean the FrameWork can work.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks. But as mentioned in the post I am actually using
>   Fody(github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged). Which automatically implements
>   that

I have checked the complied class, by using [Fody PropertyChanged](http://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) the property changed notification **wasn't successfully implemented**.

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public bool IsLocalSearchEnabled { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SetBinding();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public void SetBinding()
    {
        Binding assetsVisibilityBinding = new Binding();
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Source = this;
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("IsLocalSearchEnabled");
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Converter = Resources["BooleanToVisibilityConverter"] as IValueConverter;
        assetsStackPanel.SetBinding(StackPanel.VisibilityProperty, assetsVisibilityBinding);
    }
}
```

I would suggest you reporting issue to Fody to fix it.

The standard way as follows:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool isLocalSearchEnabled;
    public bool IsLocalSearchEnabled
    {
        get { return isLocalSearchEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (value != isLocalSearchEnabled)
            {
                isLocalSearchEnabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsLocalSearchEnabled");
            }
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SetBinding();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public void SetBinding()
    {
        Binding assetsVisibilityBinding = new Binding();
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Source = this;
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("IsLocalSearchEnabled");
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        assetsVisibilityBinding.Converter = Resources["BooleanToVisibilityConverter"] as IValueConverter;
        assetsStackPanel.SetBinding(StackPanel.VisibilityProperty, assetsVisibilityBinding);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Or you can easily use a wrapper class: [BindableBase](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Notifications/cs/Notifications/Helpers/BindableBase.cs)**